# Keyboard remapping for Onenote 2016 on Windows 7

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, onenote, onenote-api

I used to use Autohotkey to remap keys for the ease of text editing. For example, I remap Alt + i/j/k/l to up/left/down/right. However, autohotkey is not available in my working environment. I'm wondering whether there is a way to use macro or API to do the remapping in Onenote 2016.

I did some research and found that it's not easy, since macro is not available for Onenote and I cannot use Onetastic in my working environment either. There are also a lot of documents on the onenote API and I don't know where to get started.

Can anyone provide some guidance on this? It will be great if someone can provide some sample code! I have onentoe 2016 on windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible through the Onenote API, https://dev.onenote.com/docs
As you cannot modify the existing hotkey configuration of the application.

There is a similar question, and it seems some hotkeys are editable by registry (to which you most likely have no access), or Onenote itself has options to change hotkeys:
https://superuser.com/questions/199422/how-to-disable-or-change-the-windowss-hotkey-in-onenote

You wrote that autohotkey is not available in your working environment, yet its probably the only solution.
You could also bundle your script to an exe; so not the complete Autohotkey has to be installed.

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe